# One Hot Encode Labels for Object Detection?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

Currently, the labels for my object detection model are like: [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, class].

Would one hot encoding the classes be beneficial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! it is important because it helps the data to be rescaled. and as the numeric values are more easy to determine the probability for our values.

Comment: I'm looking at this EfficientDet Repo on Github: https://github.com/calmisential/EfficientDet_TensorFlow2. And he doesn't seem to be using OHE on the classes.

Comment: It depends on the dataset he is using. What if he is already using binary class dataset. so to make your classes binary and easy to use you can use one-hot-encoder. make sure your classes arent in string.